# Can a backend service have multiple SignalR connections?

Tags: signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

I have the problem and I am trying to determine if SignalR is a viable approach to the problem before I move forward. I need have a web service in Asp .NET that connects to a front-end client. This web service has to have a persistent connection to a separate server. For certain reasons, each user signed into the system has to have a unique connection to the server. Is this possible using SignalR? Is it optimal or will there be high overhead?

Thank you for any help

Comment: What is exactly your question? You want to know if each client will have a unique persistent connection to the server?

Comment: I want to know if SignalR is a good approach for having multiple separate persistent connections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, SignalR is the way to go. Each client start a unique persistent connection to the server and have this signalR unique connection ID. You can read more about [SignalR connection here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/handling-connection-lifetime-events).